# Is there a built in datatype or a gem for table data-structures in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, ruby-2.0

I need to represent and work with tables in my Ruby application. By "tables", I mean data structures with columns and rows. I need to be able to remove/append/insert columns and rows, as well as reference cells by row/column. Options for column headers, column types etc. is a  plus. I once implemented such a data structure in Python and it ended up just above 1000 lines, so I'd rather use a pre-existing solution.

Are there any built-in data structures or gems that provide this functionality?

Comment: Sounds more like an array to me

Comment: @Borodin: It's a lot like a two-dimensional array, and indeed that's how I stored the rows in my Python implementation, but there also needs to be much more than that.

Answer (score 2):

If you are happy using SQL DDL to manipulate the structure, and SQL queries to manipulate and extract the data, then you can use a database. That doesn't have to mean client/server, or other large-scale architectures; perhaps a good fit to your requirements is SQLite.

If you make use of SQLite (http://www.sqlite.org/about.html) and the `sqlite3` gem, you should also be able to run the database using in-memory mode, if all you want is the data structures it allows during run-time:

```
require 'sqlite3'
db = SQLite3::Database.new ":memory:"
```

Comment: Interesting, I didn't think of this. I'm already using sqlite3 in my application for other purposes. The disadvantage is very limited table editing support. Sqlite3 only allows for renaming tables and (i think) adding columns. It is not possible to move or delete columns.

Comment: It is possible to rename a table, create a new one with new desired structure, and copy the old data in. And of course possible to abstract that with a custom method. Also, for dropping columns, it is possible to maintain an array of the column names you are interested in, and not select "soft deleted" columns. However, that will of course impact the amount of time you have nominally saved from re-implementing the Python version of your structure.

Comment: I'm +1-ing this as a good suggestion, but I won't accept it since it still requires me to write a lot of code before I can start working with tables.

Answer (score 1):

coming from Java I also searched for somthing like Guava's [Table](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Table.html) , but what about a simple hash in hash like this:

```
table = {
        'row 1' => { 'column A' => '1A' , 'column B' => '1B' },
        'row 2' => { 'column A' => '2A' , 'column B' => '2B' },
        }
```

you can access it like:

```
table['row 1']['column A']
```

Comment: What about column headers? Sorting? Adding or deleting columns? That's the kind of stuff that would be included in an actual tabular data type